# Linq. Query Sum on dataset

Tags: linq

I'm a beginner in linq.
I would like to write this query in linq.
Select SUM(importo), anno From(
Select anno, Importo from[Archivio].[dbo].[AAA]
union
Select anno, importo From[Archivio].[dbo].[BBB]) as prova 
group by Anno order by anno.

I wrote this:

```
DataTable Tab_AAA = DS_AAA.Tables[0];
                DataTable Tab_BBB = DS_BBB.Tables[0];

IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
(from A in DS_AAA.AsEnumerable()
select A).Union(from B in DS_BBB.AsEnumerable()
select B)
```

now I can not enter the sum and the group by.
Thank you all

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You already know `Union`, now proceed to `GroupBy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the objects that you are using must be something like this

```
public class AnnoImporto
    {
        private int _anno;
        private double _importo;
        private string _altro;


        public AnnoImporto(int aAnno, double aImp, string aAltro)
        {
            _anno = aAnno;
            _importo = aImp;
            _altro = aAltro;
        }

        public int Anno
        {
            get { return _anno; }
            set { _anno = value; }
        }

        public double Importo
        {
            get { return _importo; }
            set { _importo = value; }
        }

        public string Altro
        {
            get { return _altro; }
            set { _altro = value; }
        }
    }
```

surely you have the year and the amount, think to "altro" as generic eventual other fields. I built two lists of AnnoImporto objects, but the following code will work even on lists of different object (of course, as I just said, just having year and amount...)

```
List<AnnoImporto> aaa = new List<AnnoImporto>();
            List<AnnoImporto> bbb = new List<AnnoImporto>();

            aaa.Add(new AnnoImporto(2015, 10,"blabla"));
            aaa.Add(new AnnoImporto(2014, 20, "blabla"));
            aaa.Add(new AnnoImporto(2013, 15, "blabla"));
            aaa.Add(new AnnoImporto(2012, 5, "blabla"));
            aaa.Add(new AnnoImporto(2011, 40, "blabla"));

            bbb.Add(new AnnoImporto(2011, 50, "blabla"));
            bbb.Add(new AnnoImporto(2013, 20, "blabla"));
            bbb.Add(new AnnoImporto(2015, 15, "blabla"));

            var aaa_mod = from a in aaa
                          select new
                          {
                              Anno = a.Anno,
                              Importo = a.Importo
                          };

            var bbb_mod = from b in bbb
                          select new
                          {
                              Anno = b.Anno,
                              Importo = b.Importo
                          };

            var unione = aaa_mod.Union(bbb_mod);

            Console.WriteLine("controlliamo la nuova lista:");

            foreach (var p in unione)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{p.Anno}, {p.Importo}");
            }

            var somme = from p in unione
                        orderby p.Anno
                        group p.Importo by p.Anno into q
                        select new
                        {
                            Anno = q.Key,
                            ImportoTotale = q.Sum()
                        };

            Console.WriteLine("controlliamo le somme:");

            foreach (var p in somme)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{p.Anno}, {p.ImportoTotale}");
            }
```

I followed step by step your query: first I selected in aaa and in bbb only the fields you need, I made the union of the results and I checked it. Then I did the group by to calculate sums by year.

Comment: Cabbage ...
It will take me a long time to figure it out.

Common thanks